# Brand new ColmeanCT200U-EX not wanting to stay running

Tags: engine, power, valve-cover, mini-bike, coleman

I just purchased a brand new pre-assembled Coleman CT200U-EX mini bike. I'm a newbie with this.

I've only ridden it about 3 hours or so at this point. This week its been acting up. Today while starting, with the choke on, it doesn't want to stay running. It's putting out some black smoke and I can see where the valve cover is, its a little discolored. I don't know if it's getting hot there or if it's from the exhaust. I have tried everything. I have tested the spark plug as well as the gaping, (has spark) changed both the oil and fuel, checked the air filter (super clean). Something is very off. I am attaching the picture where I am pointing to the discoloration. Any recommendations? This unit is technically under warranty. I also have a small video

Please and thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't see any pic or video? Also, if the exhaust is black, that indicates a fueling issue, as in excess fuel. More than likely it's getting flooded out by the carb. Maybe a float is stuck and leaving the needle valve open to just dump fuel in.

Comment: It won’t let me add a photot

Comment: Once the engine has started, you are meant to turn the choke off.  Does the engine run with the choke off?

Comment: If this is brand new then it's under warranty, you should be contacting Coleman to get it fixed. I you mess with it you could void the warranty.

Comment: As GdB: if you attempt to fix the problem yourself you might invalidate the warranty.

Comment: well...I replaced the spark plug today and its running. Im going to keep my eyes on it while  its on warranty but for now Im up and running again.......zoom zoom.